# If $f(x,y) = cx $ and $0<x<y<1$ prove that $E[x] = 1/2$ where X,Y are positive random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I worked as such: $$\int_0^1\int_0^y cxdxdy=1 \rightarrow c=6$$. Also:
$$f_x(x) = \int_x^1 6xdy = 6(1-x)x$$
So now I need: $$E[X] = \int_0^yx(6(1-x))dx$$. **This is y-dependent , the result is not.** What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
$**Sketch of an Alternative Solution:**

(I'll leave the formal details and filling in the blanks to you.) Consider that

$$\E[X] = \E[\E[X \mid Y]]$$

Then

$$\E[ X \mid Y = y] = \int_\R x f_{X \mid Y=y} (x) \, d x$$

We know that

$$f_{X \mid Y=y}(x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$$

You can then see that

$$f_Y(y) = \int_\R f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, d x = 3y^2$$

Therefore,

$$f_{X \mid Y=y}(x) = \frac{2x}{y^2}$$

giving

$$\E[ X \mid Y=y ] = \frac{2}{y^2} \int_0^y x^2 \, dx = \frac{2}{3} y$$

Thus,

$$\E[X] = \frac 2 3 \E[Y]$$

Observe that

$$\E[Y] = \int_\R y f_Y(y) \, d y = \int_0^1 3y^3 \, dy = \frac 3 4$$

And so,

$$\E[X] = \frac 2 3 \cdot \frac 3 4 = \frac 1 2$$

as desired.

Comment: when we calculate E[Y] why do we pick as a low end 0 and not x? for y. That's what I missed

Comment: Because (for appropriate values of $x$), $y$ can ultimately be anything in $(0,1)$. The pdf of $Y$ generally should not depend on another variable.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly obtained,

$f_X(x) = 6 x (1-x) , ~ 0 \lt x \lt 1$

So, $ \displaystyle E(X) = \int_0^1 x f_X(x) ~ dx$

$  \displaystyle = \int_0^1 6x^2 (1-x) ~ dx = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: but why the upper end is 1 and not y?

Comment: Because you are finding expected value of marginal distribution. You have already found marginal density $f_X(x)$. If you want to find $E(X)$ directly from joint density, you will do $E[X] =   \iint x\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dx\,dy$ and then the limits will be $0 \leq x \leq y$ and $0 \leq y \leq 1$